# In ConEmu I can't change the PROMPT when using cygwin bash

Tags: cmd, console, cygwin, conemu

In conemu using cmd I can edit the prompt nice and easy in the CmdInit.cmd file - I do this because I don't like the prompt spread over two lines.

However I can't seem to do the same trick when I select the startup in settings to be bash::Cygwin.

I see that the CmdInit.cmd is dos commands, so I could create a startup.sh? not sure how I invoke it.

Also the PROMT variable does not seem to exist in the bash mode - even though there is a very long two-line prompt. How can I change it? Where are the defaults even taken from?

Comment: Your question doesn't relate to ConEmu. Learn about bash profiles and PS1.

Comment: @Maximus ahh,,, you mean this is a bash setting and not to do with ConEmu? I'll take a look, thanks

Comment: Your question helped me find where to change this setting in ConEmu on Windows.